# Hangfire Multiple Recurring Job Schedule base app settings

Tags: c#, .net, cron, .net-6.0, hangfire

I have a appsettings.json file where I would like to load my schedules by seconds:

```
{
  "Schedules": [
    {
      "IntervalInSeconds": 15,
      "TimeStart": "00:00",
      "TimeEnd": "23:59"
    },
    {
      "IntervalInSeconds": 60,
      "TimeStart": "00:00",
      "TimeEnd": "23:59"
    },
    {
      "IntervalInSeconds": 300,
      "TimeStart": "00:00",
      "TimeEnd": "23:59"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Schedules are already injected. Here is where I would like to execute it:

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
    private readonly List<Schedule> _schedules;

    public Scheduler(IOptions<List<Schedules>> scheduleOptions)
    {
        _schedules = scheduleOptions.Value;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {

        foreach (var schedule in _schedules)
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine($"Hello World!"), <<My Schedule here>>);
        }

    }
}
```

How can I convert my schedule into CRON expression. I have read that it has a minimum of 1 minute. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?